# PHP-@ in while(@$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I have some php code like

```
$query="SELECT RollNo,Name FROM student" ;
$result = $mysql->execute_sql_query($query);
while(@$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $studentArray[] = array("rollNo" => $rows['RollNo'], "name" => $rows['Name']);      
 }
```

My doubt is why use @ in the line

while(@$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: it doesn't throw error means.. it spressed error message

Comment: It suppresses errors -> http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Is your question about best practices, or about what `@` means?

Comment: quick comment, as the question is already closed.. the `@` at that line makes no sense, if one wants to use it at all, it should be before a function or when referencing a variable member ($a[x]).. And the obigatory warning: use mysqli or pdo, never relay on the pure mysql_* functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suppresses error messages - see [Error Control Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) in the PHP manual.